# How should I study for maths? I'm in high school and can't seem to improve math grade

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, self-learning

I'm in 12th grade and I have been getting C's in Maths. I studied tons and solved tons of exercises. Not enough?

I'd solved all the exercises as I could do to balance with having a  bit of free time. It was enough.

But solving exercises doesn't work.

How should I study?

Comment: For us it's impossible to know your exact situation, and your strengths and weaknesses. Do you know why you got C's and not A's? If I were you, I would look at the problems that I got wrong and study the material that was used to solve those.

Comment: Have you been checking that your solutions are correct and going back to make sure you understand the ones you got wrong? Have you been focusing on understanding rather than rote memorization? Have you been identifying gaps in your understanding of the basics and filling in the gaps? How about going to the teacher to ask for help when you get stuck on a particular problem?

Comment: You might be interested in the coursera on-line course, "Learning How to Learn": https://www.coursera.org/learn/learning-how-to-learn

Comment: @awkward Did you find that Coursera course to be useful? Maybe I'll check it out.

Comment: @littleO I myself am long past being enrolled in school (although I still consider myself a student), but I took the course anyway and learned a lot of good ideas I wish I had known when I was in school.

Comment: Have you tried Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange? You're asking about learning, which is their subject, and they might have some good ideas.

Answer (score 2):

MSE is likely not the right place for such a question, and the answer will vary greatly with your own personality, which we don't know.

There are many unknowns here: what's the goal? Better grades I guess? But why? Do you want to study maths at a higher level, is it what you want or a requirement? Do you even enjoy maths? You seem to want free time: when I was in high school, maths *was* my free time. I don't want to criticize, I just try to understand how you feel about it.

If you have done tons of exercises, I assume you have the computational skills, but maybe do not see the big picture. Usually exercises are made to help see it, but maybe it's not enough here - and I don't think doing *tons* of exercises will help, I'd rather do a limited but carefully chosen set of exercises, that help me on specific areas I don't know very well yet. That's why the teacher is here usually : he will choose according to the needs of the classroom.

If you enjoy maths (and even if you don't), I suggest you try to tackle problems you find interesting and hard enough that the solution is not obvious. During your free time, why not? You could start with what is called [recreational mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recreational_mathematics) as this will teach you much about logic and how to think about problems and more generally about mathematics. You could also try problems from real life (could be applications of geometry and trigonometry, for instance, but not only that).

Apart from that, exercises are certainly a good thing, but you should also be able to understand the proofs. A good habit is to redo the proofs, and to try to change the hypotheses and see what breaks in the proof.

Just my two cents

Comment: Hey! I do enjoy maths and i want to study cs in the guture. My goal is to have more free fime for other things i enjoy ans get good grades.

Comment: @tigron123 No problem with that :)